# Fetch Info from other page and use in function on current page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this in document ready...

```
var fetchedInfo;

var url = 'https://example.com/page2';
            $.get(url, function(response) {
                fetchedInfo = $('#id').find('a').attr('href');
                alert(fetchedInfo);
            });
```

but on the alert I'm just getting 'undefined'.

The goal is to, from Page1, fetch a link from a div with a unique ID which is on Page2 of my site and use it for a Page1 function.  Sessions wouldn't work because I can't navigate away from the page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to find the link in the current page itself in that code. Try parsing the response with jQuery like:

```
var fetchedInfo;
$.get("https://example.com/page2", function(res) {
   fetchedInfo = $(res).find("div#id a").attr("href");
   alert(fetchedInfo);
});
```

Comment: Does this code not work if the info on the other page is dynamically created? I keep getting 'undefined'..

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without using jquery

```
<!--we can load the page in an iframe, then get the html out of it-->
<iframe id="target" src="https://example.com" ></iframe>
<script>
  //this gets the html from the iframe
  var targetHTML = document.getElementById('target').contentWindow;

  //this gets the element from the html
  var targetTag = targetHTML.document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML;

  alert(targetTag);
</script>
```

Comment: Does this go in Document Ready? Sorry, newbie here.